# What type of class do I need for this?

Tags: c++

I want to create a class that is usable without being instanced, but that can also be instanced. Similar to a math class I suppose.

Thanks

Comment: Can you say what you're trying to accomplish? It's hard to be sure that simply adding static methods to a class has anything to do with what you really need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add static methods to the class, you can call them like this

```
 ClassName::staticMethod();
```

You are not stopped from also creating instances of this class.

Comment: @Milo -- If you declare an object of the class, you can call static methods with a (.)

Answer (score 0):

A regular class with a constructor with static class functions.